# How to set individual event for all div

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div id=ControlId>
    <span>Select Option</span> 
</div>
</div>

<div id=ControlId + "_child"  style="display: none" > 
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" style="width: 165px" ><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" /> option 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" style="width: 165px" ><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" /> option 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" style="width: 165px" ><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="dog" /> option 3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I have added this `div` more than one time in my page. I dynamically change `ControlId`. I have added following code in jQuery `click` event only applied for last added control

```
$("#" + ControlId).click(function () {
    $("#" + ControlId + "_child").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#" + ControlId + "_child").toggle();
});
```

How to get event for all ControlId's click event only applied for last added control?

If added one time , working fine more than one time means got problem

Comment: @Shobit Sharma   Thx for the edit, makes really more sense now

Answer (score 2):

Try this if the main div is the parent of `"#" + ControlId + "_child"`:

```
$('div[id$="_child"]').parent().on('click', function(){
    var child = $(this).find('div[id$="_child"]').last();
    child.fadeIn("slow");
    child.toggle();
});
```

However, I **strongly** advise against your current approach. Try this instead:

```
 <div id=ControlId class="control-main">
 <span>Select Option</span> 

 <div id=ControlId + "_child"  class="control-child" style="display: none" > 
 // your other html here
 </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.control-main', function(){
    $('.control-child').last().fadeIn("slow").toggle();
});
```

Comment: @user1209050 - following what? Have you started using classes and my code?

Comment: thanks for your answer , i have added class and access still not working 
                             $("." +ControlId).parent().click(function () {
                    $("." +ControlId).last().toggle();

Comment: i gave same as ID for class div id=ControlId class=ControlId>

Comment: @user1209050 - please stop using the `ControlId` variable in event handlers. You're still not using classes properly, it should be like my example: `<div id=ControlId class="control-main">`.

Comment: @ Joe : i have added more than one time same set of coding . all times same class need to give

Comment: for the  requirement i have added in loop set of codes , one time means working fine with my code

Comment: @user1209050 - the class method will **definitely** work. Could you post your code here: http://pastebin.com and tell my the link so I can take a look?

Comment: i have adding inside js file , i have biggest application . normally i will add inside td tag for every time i have entered part of code

Comment: it seems controlID taken for last added Div only , events not resisted for particular

Comment: Change this: `var $parameterElement = $('<div id="' + ControlId + '" ></div>');` to this: `var $parameterElement = $('<div id="' + ControlId + '" class="control-main"></div>');. Then change `var $childdiv = $('<div id="' + .ControlId + '_child" style="display: none;max-height:250px; overflow-y:auto"/>');` to `var $childdiv = $('<div id="' + .ControlId + '_child" class="control-child" style="display: none;max-height:250px; overflow-y:auto"/>');`

Comment: Just in my answer, this: `$(document).on('click', '.control-main', function(){
    $('.control-child').last().fadeIn("slow").toggle();
});`

Comment: whether  it's working if we add more time in looping ? i think not working

Comment: Using that click code should work for all the `.control-main` as long as you've added the classes in your loop code.

Comment: still not working , if i click first div opened second added div ( i have added two times )